# Homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}_{10}$ to $\Bbb{Z}_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $f$ : $\Bbb{Z}_{10}$ $\rightarrow$ $\Bbb{Z}_5$
be defined as

For $x \in \mathbb Z_{10}, f(x) = 2x\pmod 5\in \mathbb Z_{5}$

I need to show that $f$ is a homomorphism.

Now here $f(\bar1) = \bar2$.

If $f$ is a homomorphism then order of $\bar2$ that is $5$ must divide order of $\bar1$ that is $10$ which is the case here.

I  also know that $\bar1$ is a generator of $\Bbb{Z}_{10}$.

But how could this ensure that $f$ will definitely be a homomorphism?

Comment: What does it even mean that f(x)=2x?  Where does 7 go, for example?

Comment: To four I think

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Now let's see... Is 2 a generator of Z5?

Comment: homomorphism of which structure ? the additive group, the multiplicative group, the ring ?

Comment: Yes..So every element in the image will be of form 2x. How does that ensure that f is a homomorphism?

Comment: @zwim..The additive group

Answer (score 2):

The map $f$ is the composition of multiplication by $2$ in $\mathbf Z/10\mathbf Z$, which is obviously an endomorphism of $\mathbf Z/10\mathbf Z$, by the canonical  projection $\mathbf Z/10\mathbf Z\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$ which results from the 3rd isomorphism theorem:
$$\mathbf Z/10\mathbf Z\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/10\mathbf Z\big/5\mathbf Z/10\mathbf Z\simeq\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z.$$

Answer (score 0):

An (additive) group homomorphism is a function $f : G \to H$ satisfying $f(a + b) = f(a)  + f(b)$.

You can show that the map $f(x) = 2x\pmod 5\in \mathbb Z_{5}$ is a group homomorphism by show that for any two elements $a,b \in \mathbb Z_{10}$ that $f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)$. Let's calculate both sides of that individually:

- $f(a + b) = 2 (a + b)$
- $f(a) + f(b) = 2 a + 2 b$

and these two formulas are equal by distributivity of multiplication. So we have a group homomorphism.

Comment: So..f :$\Bbb{Z}_{12} $ $\rightarrow$ $\Bbb{Z}_{10}$ defined as f(x) = 3x should also be a homomorphism?

Comment: You're OK as long as $1$ is sent to $0,$ or to a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_5.$